# Meaning of "Denshosha" - Memory Keeper

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

In reading articles about survivors of Hiroshima (*hibakusha*), I learned that there are designated individuals, *denshosha*, who are tasked with learning and recording the memories of the survivors of the bombing.

Is *denshosha* a term specific to the "memory-keeping" of the *hibakusha*, or does it have a more general meaning of simply "memory-keeper", i.e. it makes sense outside of the concept of the *hibakusha*?

(I do not study Japanese, and I do not know the Kanji/written form of these words.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not specific to hibakusha. It's written 伝承者 (den sho sha), and the last sha means "person". 伝承 means keeping knowledge through generations, usually by oral means or by teaching.
Hibakusha is written 被爆者 (hi baku sha), where hi means "exposed" and baku "bomb" or "blast". Sha is again "people".